# Issue with presenting custom size ViewController modally in ios 8 with keyboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8

I am displaying a view controller modally with navigation controller in iPad with custom size, but when the keyboard shows up, the frame size of the view controller gets changed. Its working perfectly on iOS 7, but I am having this issue when run it on iOS 8.

Code to present view:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:controllerToShow];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[[AppDelgate instance].rootViewController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

//in opening viewcontroller class frame is set 
  #define view_height 400
 #define view_width 700

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation ==   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication   sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)    {
          self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(162, 200, view_width, view_height);
     }else {
       self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(([AppDelgate instance].rootViewController.view.frame.size.width - 700)/2, 250, view_width, view_height);
     }
}
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved it by adding

```
-(CGSize)preferredContentSize{
   return  CGSizeMake(view_width, view_height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the private view hierarchy of system views is never a good idea.

You should use existing custom presentation and transition technologies (`UIModalPrestationCustom` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`) to achieve what you are attempting to do using public API.